# VBA: Getting error '1004' while trying to define Range object (WorkSheets/ActiveSheet used)

Tags: excel, vba, find

```
Sub GoToCont()

    Ind = ActiveCell.Value                        'value I am searching for
    RPointer = ActiveCell.Row                     'Pointer for active cell row
    Dim Mark As Range                             'Tried defining Mark because I kept getting errors when trying reference the cell directly in the Find Method
    Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Range(RPointer, 1)     'Debug shows Mark=None and this is where I get '1004'

    Columns(1).Find(What:=Ind, After:=Mark, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=2).Activate

End Sub
```

I am basically trying to find a value in the first column that matches the value of the active cell, starting from the current row, going up the column.
Suggestions on other ways to do it are welcome - But, I'd like to also know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the help ;)

P.S - I will wrap the ActiveCell commands, I just kept it as simple as possible until I get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in the way the line `Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Range(RPointer, 1)` is written.

It should either be `Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Cells(RPointer, 1)` or `Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & RPointer)`

Comment: Thanks! I tried the first syntax you wrote down: "Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Cells(RPointer, 1)" - it didn't work for me, i'll try the second

Comment: "Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Cells(RPointer, 1)" - and although it did point to the right cell it returned it's value instead of the object itself. How is it used to return a Range object?

Comment: Both variations return error 91 because it sets Mark as the content of the cell instead of the pointer to the cell itself. which is weird because i read the Cells property documents and it says it returns a Range object, But it's returning a string.. any thoughts?

Comment: @Rocobop - what exactly is returning a `String`? Are you `Debug.Print` ing something? Side note: don't chain an `Activate` to the end of the `Find` line. You first have to test whether the `Find` succeeded. Also, that hard-coded `2` should be `xlPrevious`.

Comment: ok got it (about testing the 'Find' and the hard-coded '2'). And I am just debugging and hovering over the variables - it shows the stopped value when you do that. I linked a screenshot 2 comments ago

Comment: @Rocobop: I think the error 91 is because the find method return a range object. So if you add something like `dim resultcell as range` and `set resultcell = columns(1).find...` without the `.activate` at the end, you should resolve this. Then you could add a line `resultcell.activate` if you need to activate it, for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

They way a Range Object is formed is `Range (cell1, cell2)`.

You are trying to declare it with `Range (Row, Column)`.

To make it work you should change it to `Range("A" & RPointer)`, to get the first Row in Column A.

[See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object))

Comment: Ok, trying it now. Actually read the glossary but this is my first tie trying VBA so maybe some of the text was to cryptic for me :)

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with the two answers above in as far as your intention is correct. You are trying to define a cell and use the correct syntax for doing so. But it seems you got mixed up between *Cell* and *Range*. My colleagues above correctly point out that you should use the syntax to define a *Range* if you wish to define a range. I differ in suggesting that you shouldn't define a cell as a range. A cell is a cell and you are right in trying to use cell syntax.

```
Dim Mark as Range
Dim Cell as Range
Set Mark = Range("A1")
Set Cell = Cells(1, "A")
```

The variation `Set Mark = Range("A" & RPointer")` works perfectly but is lousy VBA because it adapts Excel worksheet syntax into VBA. Once you try to write advanced code where both row and column are calculated variables this method is far to convoluted to be practicable. It shouldn't be recommended to you here. You should use `Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Cells(RPointer, 1)`. `Set Mark = ActiveSheet.Cells(RPointer, "A")` may be easier to read and that's why I use it at times if the column will not be calculated. Since you have already advanced to referencing cells with `(RPointer, 1)` stick with that method.

BTW, using the Find function to `Activate` a cell is asking for trouble (the *What* isn't found*). It also contravenes the rule never to `Select` or `Activate` anything while using VBA except under very few and very particular circumstances (which don't apply here). The Find function returns a range object. Therefore ...

```
Dim Fnd as Range
Set Fnd = Columns(1).Find(What:=Ind, After:=Mark, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=2)
If not Fnd Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: `The variation Set Mark = Range("A" & RPointer") works perfectly but is **LOUSY** VBA because it adapts Excel worksheet syntax into VBA.` I disagree with you.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Which part of my statement do you disagree with. Do you consider `"A" & R)` core VBA? If so, we must settle on disagreeing.

Comment: You calling it "Lousy"

Comment: Both `Cells` and `Range` are part of the Excel Object Model. How is `Cells` better than `Range`, or somehow more "pure" VBA, if there is even such a thing? And if you're using the column syntax `"A"` within `Cells`... that's "adapting Excel worksheet syntax" too. Furthermore, a cell *is* a `Range`.

Comment: @BigBen I admitted as much and didn't recommend it. However, I believe that code should be as precise and logical as possible. Where the OP wants to define a member of the `Cells` collection and uses the correct syntax to do so he shouldn't be guided to define a `Range` instead even if the outcome, for him, would be strikingly similar.

Comment: @Variatus then please show OP how a `Cell` should be defined... `Dim cell as Range` is my point. Besides, OP is dealing with the *first* column - it's not variable at all. Using `Cells` is perfectly fine too... it's just the extra fluff in your question that I completely disagree with.

Comment: @BigBen I tried to show exactly that. `Dim Cell As Range` is intended to be controversial so as to set him thinking. However, I believe he knows that `Cells` are `Ranges`. Anyway, I'm glad an relieved to see that we are nearing a point where we might all agree.

Comment: `Dim cell as Range` is not controversial at all... because a cell is a `Range`.

Comment: I appreciate the conversation - here's my thoughts: I tried it with the cells method at first - because I got exactly what the first two comments said about the arguments sent to Range method - but it gave me the value of the cell instead of a pointer to the cell itself (pointer to range object). this obviously is not what I need to sent to the Find method. So I'll change it the way you guys said (when using Range in this example). But - is there a way to use Cells method so it returns the cell itself instead of it's value? Which is only one of the properties of the object?

Comment: A `Range` has many properties. One of them is the `Value`. One of them is the default property. The *default property* is one VBA presumes if you don't specify any. Compare a range to a car. Its default property is transportation. "I'll take the car". Nobody will believe you literally "take the car" and put it in your pocket. But that's what you do with `Range("A1") = 123.` You mean `Range("A1").Value = 123` But what about `Range("A1") = Range("C3")`? Correct! This copies the entire cell C3, including the value and 47 other properties. `Range("A1").Value = Range("C3").Value` is different.

Comment: `After:=Cells(1, 1)` does specify the cell and not its value. Because the `After` property requires a range VBA doesn't consider that you might mean the `Value` property. Try `After:=Cells(1, 1).Value`. You will get an error because VBA expects a range.

Comment: I feel like this has gone down a tangent... but `Range("A1") = Range("C3")` does not copy the entire cell `C3` to `A1`. Completely agree with being explicit about the `.Value` though.